# How to implement shopping basket which plays nice with Paypal's "Add Item" button

Tags: html, paypal

I am a relative beginner writing a website in html using Microsoft VWDE, for my choir.
I want to sell tickets to our concert(s), on-line.
I would like the user to be able to enter the number of tickets required for any price (Full, Student, Concession), hit a button and be taken to the Paypal checkout / basket page with the items listed. 
This ought to be possible with Paypal's Add Item button against each seat type, but on pressing the button for just one seat you are taken immediately to the Paypal page (without having chance to press the button for the second seat price if you wanted to! You have to navigate back to your own web page)
So I considered Open Source offers like Open Cart, but they are way too big for me. Paypal's help on this was (eventually) to say that I needed some sort of Shopping basket functionality (begs the question of what does the Add Item button achieve!?!). 
Don't mind writing code for this, what does anyone recommend?

Thanks and apologies for my ignorance...

Ali

Answer (score 0):

Most hosts have a nice one click install (like [Softaculous](http://www.softaculous.com/)) for installing shopping carts. It would be the quickest and the easiest way to get a shopping cart up and running!
Most of them have PayPal plugins too.